# How to save in a csv file so that every attribute is in a new column using "json2csv"

Tags: json, node.js, file, csv

So I use "Json2csv" and I tried an example:

```
   var fs = require('fs'); 
   var json2csv = require('json2csv');
   var fields = ['car', 'price', 'color'];
   var fieldNames = ['Car Name', 'Price USD','Color'];
   var myCars = [
        {
           "car": "Audi",
           "price": 40000,
            "color": "blue"
        }, {
            "car": "BMW",
            "price": 35000,
            "color": "black"
        }, {
            "car": "Porsche",
            "price": 60000,
            "color": "green"
        }
    ];

    var opts = {
        data: myCars,
        fields: fields,
        fieldNames: fieldNames,
        quotes: ';'
    };
    var csv = json2csv(opts);



    fs.writeFile('file2.csv', csv, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');
    });
```

I get this :

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

As you can see it always creates for each "," a new column, but I just want for each attribute as you can see in the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing quotes ';' param in opts. It is adding extra ';' in each string which might be acting as delimiter.

```
var opts = {
    data: myCars,
    fields: fields,
    fieldNames: fieldNames
};
```

Comment: No it doesnt work. It saves entire object in one column

Comment: It works for me. what delimiters you are sing to parse csv ? Can you open csv in vim and post content here ?

Comment: @KeyNavas you got the solution ?

Comment: unfortunatlly no. What happens is that every object is stored in ONE column. Like:    Audi,40000,blue then it goes in new row : BMW, 30000, black.

Comment: see this question : See this question I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825454/how-to-save-a-csv-file-using-fast-csv-that-every-attribute-is-in-own-column