# How to save a csv File using fast-csv that every attribute is in OWN column

Tags: json, node.js, file, csv, pipe

So I tried this example:

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var csvStream = csv.createWriteStream({ headers: true }),
        writableStream = fs.createWriteStream("my.csv");

    writableStream.on("finish", function () {
        console.log("DONE!");
    });

    csvStream.pipe(writableStream);
    csvStream.write({ a: "a0", b: "b0" });
    csvStream.write({ a: "a1", b: "b1" });
    csvStream.write({ a: "a2", b: "b2" });
    csvStream.end();
```

And I get this output:

[image]

But I want this output:

[image]

Is it possible that the values of a object are in another columns using fast-csv? Or is there another way that it is possible?

Comment: I tested on my pc right now and I get the output you want. Maybe this is an issue on how you read the csv and not how you write it. Try to create the output you want and export to csv with excel or similar, and the check this csv with the one generated by node.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis I dont read the file? This file is created when I write it as you see above.

Comment: You printscreened the output of excel reading the csv, try creating the output you want in excel and save it as csv, then compare this csv with the one generated with node to see what is different.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis the generated with nodejs does not create a new column. i created the wished output in excel and there I get the output i want

Comment: @alex-rokabilis it only works in access it creates a "table" but it wont work with excell